# Which is better of following two approach to schedule and stop thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have generally seen two approaches to implement a daemon which does some work and goes to sleep and wakes up again.

1. while(flag) approach where flag is true and is set to false by some other class if we want to stop the daemon.

   ```
   while(flag){
      //do something
      Thread.sleep(10000l);
   }
   ```
2. Scheduling with ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor using fixed delay.

IMO, second approach is much more cleaner and easy to test. Could someone compare these two approach. Can first approach cause any memory issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach 2) is recommended.

Approach one is not robust to random awakenings by the underlying threading system (especially on UNIX) and also you would need to implement your own error handling

Approach two allows you to abstract from the underlying `Thread` and work with the `Runnable` or `Callable`.

Furthermore approach 1) has the problem of clock drift, i.e. your task takes a non-zero time to execute therefore it will **not** execute every ten seconds. The `ScheduledExecutorService` will actually schedule execution every second or, if it's desired, with a ten second interval.

Approach 2) provides for a simple way to schedule the thread to do something for a period of time and them kill it as per the example in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Finally, the `ExecutorSevice` is much easier to shut down that a custom thread, simply calling `executorService.shutdown()` and then `executorService.awaitTermination()` to wait for the last task to finish.

One thing you may want to note is this gem from the javadoc - " If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed". This means either that you have to be very careful about `try/catch` in your `Callable` or you need to subclass the `ScheduledExecutorService` thus (taken from the javadoc):

```
public class MyScheduledExecutor extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor {

    public MyScheduledExecutor(int corePoolSize) {
        super(corePoolSize);
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        super.afterExecute(r, t);
        if (t == null && r instanceof Future<?>) {
            try {
                Object result = ((Future<?>) r).get();
            } catch (CancellationException ce) {
                t = ce;
            } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
                t = ee.getCause();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // ignore/reset
            }
        }
        if (t != null) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 good points. Except that the last paragraph is not applicable since the OP is interested in a fixed delay and not a fixed rate scheduling scheme.

Comment: Approach 2) also has a problem with clock drift. See [this blog post](https://medium.com/@leventov/cronscheduler-a-reliable-java-scheduler-for-external-interactions-cb7ce4a4f2cd) for details.

Answer (score 3):

> Can first approach cause any memory issues?

No. The biggest issue is in managing the visibility of the `flag` variable. The `Thread` class encapsulates the concept of an interrupt flag for a reason.